# solving linear diophantine equation with inequalities

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is there an easy way to solve linear Diophantine equations with inequalities?

For example, say I have $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 \equiv k \mod m$ where:

- $a_1, a_2, k, m$ are given
- I already know $b_1, b_2$ such that $a_1b_1 \equiv a_2b_2 \equiv 1 \mod m$, so if either of the $x_1$ or $x_2$ is given, I can calculate the other one:

  $x_1 = (k - a_2x_2)b_1 \bmod m \\ x_2 = (k - a_1x_1)b_2 \bmod m$
- I wish to solve for $x_1, x_2$ where $0 < x_1 < x_{max}$, $0 < x_2 < x_{max}$.

---

For example, $a_1 = 12345678987601, a_2 = 45678901, k = 135990606993339, m = 2^{48}-1, x_{max}=10^6.$

I can find $b_1 = 179768904497071, b_2 = 154376496085921$ easily, but other than a brute-force search, I'm not sure how to find the values $x_1$ and $x_2$ (in this case $x_1 = 50603, x_2 = 12481$ but that's because I created this example)

---

Note: I used tmyklebu's solution and implemented in Python with numpy and sympy:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy.matrices import Matrix

# thanks to user tmyklebu http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151038/120

def reduce_lattice(L, verbose=False):
    """repeated pseudo-Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization
       until we get no more progress
    """
    N = L.shape[0]
    get_norm = lambda M: sum(np.amax(np.abs(M),1))
    Lnorm = None
    Lnew = L.copy()
    Lnew_norm = get_norm(Lnew)
    while Lnorm != Lnew_norm:
        for i in xrange(N):
            v = Lnew[i]
            num = np.dot(Lnew,v)
            den = np.sum(Lnew**2, axis=1)
            k = [int(np.round(x)) for x in num*1.0/den]
            k[i] = 0   # don't subtract multiples of self
            vnew = v-np.dot(k,Lnew)
            Lnew[i] = vnew
        Lnorm = Lnew_norm
        Lnew_norm = get_norm(Lnew)
    return Lnew

def solve_eqn(a1,a2,k,m,xmax):
    B = int(np.ceil(np.abs(xmax)))
    L = np.array([[m*B,0,0],
                  [a1*B,1,0],
                  [a2*B,0,1]], dtype=object)
    L1 = reduce_lattice(L)
    L2 = Matrix(L1.T)
    exact_coords=L2.LUsolve(Matrix(3,1,[k*B,0,0]))
    int_coords = Matrix(3,1,[int(c.round()) for c in exact_coords])
    soln = [int(c) for c in L2*int_coords]
    assert soln[0] == k*B
    return soln[1:]
```

and got:

```
>>> solve_eqn(a1=12345678987601, a2=45678901, 
              k=135990606993339, m=(1<<48)-1, xmax=1000000 )
[50603, 12481]
```

:-)

Comment: ...and is there supposed to be that much space around ${\rm mod}$? If not, what should I be using for MathJax?

Comment: Use \bmod instead of \mod.

Comment: hey, thanks! wait, when does the \mod form get used?

Comment: When used as a relation, i.e. $\,\  x\equiv a\mod b,\ $ means $\ x\equiv a\pmod b\ $

Comment: ah.... so I really have some of each in this question. Fixing now...

Comment: Odd that the spacing between "mod" and "m" is so large with \mod, however. I should think that spacing would be the same for both \bmod and \mod, since the difference is really with the pause between the "mod" keyword and the stuff that comes before it.

Comment: The \mod is supposed to be the same as the parenthesized \pmod but without the parens. There is extra space to signify that if modifies the whole equation (congruence), versus only one side of the equation.

Comment: no, I get why there's extra space between the preceding text (between the k and mod in $ab \equiv k \mod m$) but don't understand about the space *after* the mod. Compare to $ab \equiv k \bmod m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to pretend you want $|x_i| < x_{max}$ for $i \in \{1, 2\}$ instead of $0 \leq x_i < x_{max}$; it's straightforward to transform your problem into this form.

Consider the lattice $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by $(m, 0, 0)$, $(a_1, 1/x_{max}, 0)$, and $(a_2, 0, 1/x_{max})$.  These three vectors are called a "basis" for the lattice $L$.  Every vector in this lattice is of the form $(a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + z m, x_1/x_{max}, x_2/x_{max})$ for some integers $x_1$, $x_2$, and $z$.

If there is a vector in $L$ whose $\infty$-norm distance to $(k, 0, 0)$ is less than 1, then there are $x_1$, $x_2$, and $z$ such that $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + m z = k$ (since the first coordinate is always an integer), $|x_1| < x_{max}$, and $|x_2| < x_{max}$.  Conversely, if a solution to your problem exists, it corresponds to a vector in $L$ whose $\infty$-norm distance to $(k, 0, 0)$ is less than 1.

---

So we've reduced your problem to that of finding the closest vector in $L$ to some point $p = (k, 0, 0)$.  Algorithmically, the first step is to find a "good" basis for $L$ made of "short" and "nearly orthogonal" vectors.  Then you express $p$ as a linear combination of those vectors.  Since we're interested in landing on a box with side length 1, you can derive bounds on the coefficients of the vectors in the reduced basis and then check the small, finite number of sets of coefficients satisfying those bounds.

Finding a "good" basis for $L$ is a very interesting problem in higher dimensions.  We're in three dimensions, though, so there's not a lot that can go wrong.  Repeatedly look for one vector that can be made shorter by adding or subtracting integer multiples of the other two (this is a two-dimensional closest vector problem) and replace it with the shorter version.

Firstly, other, better, algorithms for these lattice problems exist, and I'm by no means an expert on this stuff.  Secondly, there is quite probably another, simpler way to skin this cat.  The lattice-based approach generalises straightforwardly to higher dimensions (i.e. more variables) and I think the formulation of this problem using lattices is particularly elegant.

---

Working your example, you begin with the lattice basis (I scaled everything by a million and all my vectors are row vectors)

```
281474976710655000000 0 0
12345678987601000000  1 0
45678901000000        0 1
```

You can reduce this (with a little work) to the basis

```
 5000000 -123921   1584701
-2000000 -2566579  5272172
 1000000 -6801061 -5903638
```

In this basis, the vector `(135990606993339000000 0 0)` has (approximate) coordinates `(24644034888697.000457924580143 -5560521170833.99591073404456 1649390208186.00588890901)`.  If you round those coordinates to their nearest integers and see what point the rounded coordinates correspond to, it's `(135990606993339000000 50603 12481)`.  (Note that just rounding all the coordinates doesn't always give you the closest lattice vector.)

Comment: Huh, thanks. I've got to digest this + see what I can make of it. I had been able to visualize the 2-D lattice, hadn't thought of adding a 3rd dimension to handle the modulus $m$, but I think I get the gist of what you're talking about.

Comment: Got all of that except the "You can reduce this (with a little work) to the basis" part... I don't need to see every step, but what's the basic methodology? Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization?

Comment: oh never mind, you meant this item from earlier in the post: "Repeatedly look for one vector that can be made shorter by adding or subtracting integer multiples of the other two"

Comment: e.g. in the original scaled lattice basis, if I had basis vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, the continuous analog would be to compute $v_1' = v_1 - kv_2$ with $k = \frac{v_1 \cdot v_2}{v_2 \cdot v_2}$, so the integer version would be to find the nearest integer to k?

Comment: @JasonS: For two vectors, that's it.  For three vectors, you project one vector onto the space spanned by the other two and find the closest lattice vector.  (You can just do the two-vector reduction you described here repeatedly and you'll hopefully get the same basis I did.)  I said "a little work" because my program did something like 30 reduction steps and it would be painful, not to mention unnecessary, to list them all.

Comment: @JasonS: Note that the closest-vector (or find-vector-in-cube) computation doesn't depend on having a lattice basis that's optimal in any sense.  "Better" bases that are "more orthogonal" will just make the closest-vector (or find-vector-in-cube) computation run faster because there will be fewer points to check.  In three dimensions, as long as you sorta tried, whatever basis you get is probably good enough.  In higher dimensions (say 20-30 and up), it really starts mattering.

Comment: whee! it worked, I posted a Python version of this in my question. Thanks!